# How can I create a struct type in the linux kernel (sys.c) that can be accessed by regular programs?

Tags: c, struct, kernel, system-calls

I have implemented a few of my own syscalls in the sys.c file of the linux kernel. In my implementations I used two struct types that I created in the same file. I also would like to be able to use these structs outside of the kernel. Is there a way to use kernel-prototyped structs in regular programs, in the same way that the syscalls can be accessed by the regular programs?

Specifically, I need to create one of these structs in a user program, which is then passed as an argument to the syscalls. I think I need the struct to be in sys.c because it uses "struct task_struct", which is part of linux/sched.h.

If there is a way to do this, or if I am doing something completely wrong I would be happy to know either way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual C way of using the same declarations in multiple programs (here: kernel and user program) is putting the declarations in a header file and including that in the programs. If your structure declaration uses a declaration from linux/sched.h, you may want to `#include <linux/sched.h>` in the header file. (For getting `struct task_struct`, it may be necessary to `#define __KERNEL__`. What your user program does with a task_struct, only you can tell.)